# How to use a child class property in a function written for base class

Tags: c#, object-oriented-design, inheritance

in C#, suppose I have written this function

```
public void TryToTurnOn( Device d )
{
    // some common logic

    // some more common logic
}
```

I then have a class that inherit Device that is DeviceWithAButton, I can write something like this

```
public void TryToTurnOn( Device d )
{
    // some common logic

    if( d is DeviceWithAButton) { Click(d.button) }

    // some more common logic
}
```

Or

```
public void TryToTurnOn( DeviceWithAButton d )
{
    // some common logic, duplicated

    Click(d.button)

    // some more common logic, duplicated
}
```

I do not think this is a good way to achieve this however. What is a good way to handle this situation or any pattern that we should apply?

Comment: (1) Would it make sense to make the `TryToTurnOn()` a virtual function on the `Device` class?  (2) Look into the [Template Method](https://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html) pattern.  I'm not certain that it applies to your situation (hard to tell given only what you wrote).  But look at it just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When initially looking at your first code example, the immediate thought is "*`Device` should be responsible for this stuff*":

```
public void TryToTurnOn(Device d) => d.TryTurnOn();

public class Device 
{
    public void TryTurnOn()
    {
        // some common logic

        // some more common logic
    }
}
```

But, your next example shows the rabbit hole that this approach can take us down:

```
public void TryToTurnOn(Device d) => d.TryTurnOn();

public class Device 
{
    public void TryTurnOn()
    {
        // some common logic

        Click();

        // some more common logic
    }

    protected abstracted void Click(); // all subclasses need to implement this even
                                       // if they have no button :(
}
```

I have to put that `Click` in `TryTurnOn` as it's called in the middle of the method. My subclass can't just override it and call `base.TryTurn()` at the start or end of its own implementation. This approach leads us to the fragile base class problem because I now need to be super careful over any changes I make to `TryTurnOn` as I could accidently break a child class (which I may not own if this is an API of some sort) by doing so.

So rather than taking this inheritance approach, we can use composition to avoid this problem. The simplest way of doing this is to employ interfaces. If we go back to your example (so the code is back in that separate class):

```
public void TryToTurnOn(Device d)
{
    // some common logic

    if (d is IDeviceWithButton buttonDevice) Click(buttonDevice.Button);

    // some more common logic
}
```

We are still testing for specific types, but rather than hardcoding subtypes, we have simplified it to *any* subtype that implements `IDeviceWithButton` and thus has a `Button` property.

We can go a step further though. Let's say we have devices that have toggle or rotary on/off switches as well as those devices with buttons. We probably don't want to start expanding those special cases:

```
public void TryToTurnOn(Device d)
{
    // some common logic

    if (d is IDeviceWithButton buttonDevice) Click(buttonDevice.Button);
    if (d is IDeviceWithToggleSwitch toggleDevice) Toggle(toggleDevice.Switch);
    if (d is IDeviceWithRotarySwitch rotaryDevice) Rotate(rotaryDevice.Switch);

    // some more common logic
}
```

as that quickly gets out of hand. Instead, properly compose the devices by allowing each device to have one or more supplementary methods of turning them on:

```
public class Device 
{
    public IEnumerable<ISupplementaryOnMethod> SupplementaryOnMethods { get; }

    public Device(IEnumerable<ISupplementaryOnMethod> supplementaryOnMethods)
        => SupplementaryOnMethods = supplementaryOnMethods;
}


public void TryToTurnOn(Device d)
{
    // some common logic

    foreach (method in d.SupplementaryOnMethods)
    {
        method.TryToTurnOn();
    }

    // some more common logic
}
```

That way, you avoid having to employ inheritance to solve this issue. You avoid hard-coding types as special cases. And you also allow for devices that have more than one extra means of turning them on.

Answer (score 4):

The point of having a class hierarchy is that more general classes *don't* have to know about the details of more specific classes. A base class checking for the type of its derived class is almost always a very bad sign. Instead, consider

- overriding `turnOn()` in the child class, perhaps calling `super.turnOn()` if you want additional rather than different logic
- Writing a *hook*: an abstract method called at a certain point within `turnOn()`, which does nothing in the base class, but may be defined to do additional things in child classes
- Using more complicated patterns (if necessary!), as suggested by Nick.

Comment: * Just to clarify, TryToTurnOn belong to a completely different class. Not inside the BaseClass

Answer (score -1):

A `Device` should be responsible for turning itself on. That being said, clicking a button, flipping a switch or sliding a toggle are implementation details of turning the device on. It feels like an abstraction is missing: the "control" that activates the device.

From the outside, there can be a `TryTurnOn` method on the Device object. Inside, it should have an `IDeviceActivationControl` object that does the clicking of a button, flipping of a switch or sliding of a toggle.

```
public void TryTurnOn(Device device)
{
    device.TryTurnOn();
}

public class Device
{
    private IDeviceActivationControl activationConrol;

    public Device(IDeviceActivationControl activationConrol)
    {
        this.activationConrol = activationConrol;
    }

    public void TryTurnOn()
    {
        // common logic

        activationConrol.Activate();

        // More common logic
    }
}
```

Then the Device is composed of a control that activates it:

```
new Device(new ButtonDeviceActivationControl());
new Device(new SwitchDeviceActivationControl());
new Device(new ToggleDeviceActivationControl());
```